# Extending magento 2 breadcrumbs through XML layout

Tags: cms-pages, breadcrumbs, magento-2.1.4

Is there any method to extending magento 2 breadcrumb through XML layout in cms page in order to add parent page link?

Comment: Do you got solution?

Answer (score 0):

By xml layout you can not do this, but you can do this by extending the block: `\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs`. You can do this with the module in this link: https://github.com/gr33nart/m2_greenart_breadcrumbs

Printscreen: https://goo.gl/GwoZPW

Comment: Helped you with my answer?